# iOS Post Photo to Instagram without opening Instagram App

Tags: iphone, ios, share, instagram

Is there a way to post a photo from my app to Instagram without opening the Instragram app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is not. Instagram requires photos to be sent the Instagram app via document interaction controller. (which requires the app to be installed)

Comment: there is no API for Instagarm ?

Comment: @TheTiger [There is](http://instagram.com/developer/), but it allows you to do everything but share. They want you to use their app for that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I have never used this. Just saw this link - http://instagram.com/developer/ so I asked.